# Offset link to specific page by 80px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `navbar-fixed-top` menu for my page and it works exactly as I want it to. The project I am working on requires flat design on one page. This means I need to go from the menu to specific parts of the page. Everythin works but since the `navbar` is fixed on top it covers parts of the "subpage". See this image for two browser windows next to eachother.

Question: What alternatives do I have to push the page 80px upwards (preferably without JS).

[image]

Comment: You're linking to anchors in that page? I posted a solution in my profile, look at the class .anchor assigned to the target and it won't be covered up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the bootstrap page it actually tells you that you will have to add some padding to the top of the body so that it doesn't cover your other content.

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
 body { padding-top: 70px; }
```